# MongoDB Illegal Instruction

Tags: mongodb, archlinux

When I type in "mongo" in terminal
it cannot run and shows up these thing

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

then nothing happen.

I install mongodb in arch linux.
I have create /data/db.

Comment: have you started mongod --dbpath "db location" first?

Comment: Did you get MongoDB from your system package manager or somewhere else?

Comment: This sounds like corruption, new versions of the mongo shell should produce another error if the MongoDB server isn't reachable.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of processor is this running on? There have been issues in the past with unimplemented instructions on some older processor architectures.

Can you use gdb to examine the core file, or start the mongo process under gdb and reproduce the problem, and determine

- what is the illegal instruction that is being executed?
- what is the stack backtrace at the point where the illegal instruction occurs?

Comment: I wrote a detailed blog post about it [here](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/manjaro-compile-mongodb-from-source-and-install-it-manually/). The problem is that the binaries in the official repo are compiled using an instruction set that is not supported by old 32-bit CPUs. Solution: compile it from source and install manually.

Answer (score 0):

have you started mongod --dbpath "db location" first? –  Eugene P yesterday

Did you get MongoDB from your system package manager or somewhere else? –  sudo_O yesterday

This sounds like corruption, new versions of the mongo shell should produce another error if the MongoDB server isn't reachable. –  Sammaye yesterday

I have used mongod --dbpath /data/db.
I get mongodb from pacakge manager, i have tried to compile from source, it also same.

## mongod --dbpath /data/db

```
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.024
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.027 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by                                                default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.032
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.128 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=23705 port=27017                                            dbpath=/data/db 32-bit host=xeraph.hk
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.129 [initandlisten]
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.131 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary                                           .
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.133 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to le                                            ss than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.134 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults t                                           o off for 32 bit and is currently off.
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.136 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/c                                           ore/32bit
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.138 [initandlisten]
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.139 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.140 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.141 [initandlisten] build info: Linux root-armv6-copy 3.4.76                                           -1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 15 15:31:14 MST 2014 armv7l BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_5                                           5
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.141 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.142 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/data/db" }
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.227 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on po                                           rt 28017
Tue Feb 25 13:27:46.228 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

The terminal pause there, then i login to another ssh terminal,

## mongo

Also illegal instruction.